Populate listbox at Initialization
Related post: VBA Userform ListBox - Run-Time Error 380. Could not set the List property. Invalid property value
@taller helped me streamline command button code for searching records in a listbox. I thought I could transfer that code to the Initialize procedure, but I'm not having any luck. I'm very new, so I welcome additional explanations/comments.
The following shows the OLD code which works. Per @taller, instead of listing all 125 columns widths ("0" for the 115 columns NOT in the listbox), he suggested I create an array of only the 10 columns that comprise the listbox. I attempted to follow his example, per the post in the link above, but my inexperience is glaringly obvious because the NEW code is not working.  Thank you in advance for your consideration!
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'redacted code here

    'Add items to combobox list. Each list item MUST match their respective column header.
    cboSearchItem.List = Array("Shop Order", "Suffix", "Proposal", "PO", "SO", "Quote", _
    "Transfer Order", "Customer Nickname", "End User Nickname") '1-dimensional array

    ************OLD*****************
    lstMaster.ColumnWidths = "0;0;40;48;108;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;50;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;72;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;50;35;0;0;0;0;0;0;45;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0"
    lstMaster.ColumnCount = 125  'Number of total columns
    lstMaster.List = Sheets("Master").Range("A4:DU" & Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    ********************************************
    
    ************NEW****************
    Const COL_WIDE = "40;48;108;50;72;50;35;45;100;100"
    Const COL_INDEX = "3;4;5;14;23;33;34;41;96;121" ' Column numbers that appear in ListBox
    Const START_ROW = 4 ' the first data row
    Dim aIndex
        aIndex = Split(COL_INDEX, ";")
    Dim ColCnt As Long
        ColCnt = UBound(aIndex) + 1
    With lstMaster
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = ColCnt
        .ColumnWidths = COL_WIDE
        .List = Sheets("Master").Range("A4:DU" & Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
   ********************************************** 
'redacted code here
    End With

EDIT: I've added the following code and clearly commented on where the new code starts and ends. This new code achieved the result I was going after by going from this:
lstMaster.ColumnWidths = "0;0;0;0;75;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;125;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;75;0;0;75;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;"
to this:
Const COL_WIDE = "40;48;108;50;72;50;35;45;100;100"
How can build an array like this in the Initialization code?
Private Sub cmbSearchlstMaster_Click() 'Search multiple orders button
    Dim sat    As Long
    Dim s      As Long
    Dim c      As Integer
    Dim deg1   As String
    Dim deg2   As String
    Dim RN     As Integer

    '**********NEW CODE STARTS********************  
     ' modify as needed
    Const COL_WIDE = "40,48,108,50,72,50,35,45,100,100"
    Const COL_INDEX = "3,4,5,14,23,33,34,41,96,121" ' Col index which is showed in ListBox
    Const START_ROW = 4 ' the first data row
    '**********NEW CODE ENDS***********************
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Setting to 'false' speeds up the macro
    Dim txtShopOrdNum As String: txtShopOrdNum = ""  'clear txtShopOrdNum, v13
    Sheets("Master").Activate

    'redacted code here
    
    '**********NEW CODE STARTS********************  
    Dim aIndex: aIndex = Split(COL_INDEX, ",")
    Dim ColCnt As Long: ColCnt = UBound(aIndex) + 1
    With lstMaster 'Need to clear the listbox first
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = ColCnt
        .ColumnWidths = COL_WIDE
    End With
    '**********NEW CODE ENDS***********************

    Call Main 'Progress bar
    deg2 = txtSearch.Value
    Select Case cboSearchItem.Value
        Case "Shop Order"
            RN = 5  'E 
        Case "Suffix"
            RN = 4  'D
        Case "Proposal"
            RN = 14 'O
        Case "PO"
            RN = 23 'X
        Case "SO"
            RN = 33 'AH
        Case "Quote"
            RN = 34 'AI
        Case "Transfer Order"
            RN = 41 'AP
        Case "Customer Nickname"
            RN = 96 'CR
        Case "End User Nickname"
            RN = 121 'DQ
    End Select

    '**********NEW CODE STARTS********************
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, RN).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arrData: arrData = Range(Cells(START_ROW, 1), Cells(lastRow, "DQ"))
    Dim iR As Long, arrRes()
    For sat = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        deg1 = arrData(sat, RN)
        If UCase(deg1) Like "*" & UCase(deg2) & "*" Then 'case insensitive AND searches the entire string
            ReDim Preserve arrRes(ColCnt - 1, iR)
            For c = 0 To ColCnt - 1                   'column indices, total column
                arrRes(c, iR) = arrData(sat, aIndex(c))
            Next c
            iR = iR + 1
        End If
    Next
    lstMaster.Column = arrRes
    ' OR
    ' lstMaster.List = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
    '**********NEW CODE ENDS***********************

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    lblTotalSearchResults = lstMaster.ListCount
    lblTotalOrders = Range("MASTER").Rows.Count
    
End Sub 'cmbSearchlstMaster

EDIT #2
I got a lot further and am so close. Thank you @FaneDuru for your help. My listbox populates perfectly upon initialization with the exception of formatting the column widths. How to I pair up the column number array with the column width array?
Private Sub UserForm_Initalize()

    Dim aIndex()
    Dim arr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("MASTER")
    aIndex = Array(3, 4, 5, 14, 23, 33, 34, 41, 96, 121) 'Column number
    arr = ws.Range("A4:DU" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    arr = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), aIndex) 'array containing only chosen columns
            'Application.Index(Array,Row_Number,Column_Number)
    lstMaster.List = arr

'colWidth = Array(44, 42, 108, 50, 72, 50, 35, 45, 100, 100)
End Sub


Please edit your question and add more details about "not working".  Exactly what do you mean?  Is there an error message (and if so, at what line)? Are you not getting the result you expect (and if so, at what line)? Then also explain what result you expect to get.

You have ColumnCount = 10 but 125 columns in your input range?  Seems like you skipped a few steps from the linked post where you build an array for the list instead of pointing it at a range...

@devline carnate thank you for your input. I've edited my question, added more detail and code in hopes of clarifying my ask. In a nutshell, anytime I can improve the code and make it more concise and run faster and better, is a good thing.

@Tim Williams thank you for your response. I'll revisit the code to see if I can understand what I've skipped. Honestly, the new code I was provided works great, but I'm not sure I understand exactly what it's doing and why it works. I'm a big fan of instructional comments.

@TimWilliams I added Sub Tester() procedure immediately after Option Explicit.
I had to s: Dim aIndex, ColCnt As Long, rngData, wsMaster As Worksheet, arr, ColumnSubset, lstMaster As Object
I was getting a compile error sub or function undefined. In the cmbSearchlstMaster_Click() procedure, I replaced all of the new code with Tester.
I ran the code and got Run-time error '13: Type mismatch on line: arr = ColumnSubset(rngData.Value, aIndex)

I see I forgot to include the code for ColumnSubset: see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O9w_XV1pX4zzS3cXraLOSvFY_EfvOObX/view?usp=sharing for the complete code.   You should be able to copy the relevant parts into your existing code.  There's really very little to change.

@TimWilliams I made the updates and have provided all of the code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xE-XE54KquavnLHFMYl8st8SwrKn-rCU/view?usp=sharing
Private Sub cmbSearchlstMaster_Click() the search results show all of the records as matches instead of filtering by the combo box selection in cboSearchItem, plus what's typed in the textbox: txtSearch.

Hold the phone! I got Initialize to work. See updated code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xE-XE54KquavnLHFMYl8st8SwrKn-rCU/view?usp=sharing
Now, just need to get the search procedure to work.

Added filtering to the function: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vAfrbITLIiWsTh4DGwh_lz1lHBt43-k4/view?usp=sharing

compile error: sub or function not defined in Sub Tester() procedure: ColumnSubset. I tried changing it to ColumnSubsetAndFilter and got a compile error: argument not optional.

Forget Tester - that last link is a modification of your cmbSearchlstMaster_Click method.  If you can share your workbook I will fold in my code.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12SCKruBYn-FvzcX166dIvF_WjBi6pQbk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106591725375141807281&rtpof=true&sd=true  workbook with working code.

I tried downloading, emailing it to myself, etc., so I can access the VBE to see the code, but no luck.  It is View Only.

Please, replace and add code lines as following:
Sub ReplaceCodeLines()
 'your existing code
 '.........
 'replace:
 'Const COL_INDEX = "3;4;5;14;23;33;34;41;96;121"
 'with
 Dim aIndex(): aIndex = Array(3, 4, 5, 14, 23, 33, 34, 41, 96, 121)
 
 'add the next code:____________________________________________________
 Dim arr, wsM As Worksheet
 Set wsM = ActiveSheet ' sheets("Master")
 arr = wsM.Range("A4:DU" & wsM.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row).value
 arr = Application.index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), aIndex) 'array containing only chosen columns
 '______________________________________________________________________
 
 'replace
 '.List = Sheets("Master").....
 'with
 List = arr
 ''your existing code
 
 '...........
End Sub


@Yodelayheewho Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it work as you need? Is it something not clear enough?

I need a little more hand-holding. This is not clear to me on what to do. You've not mentioned Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() and the edits I need to make. It appears you want me to create a new procedure? This newbie is lost.
